# Why does Windows 7 ask me to debug the program?

Tags: windows-7

I was installing Linux on Virtualbox when Virtualbox froze. A popup box asked me if I wanted to debug Virtualbox.

Why would Windows 7 ask me, the front-end user, if I want to debug a program? Is this breaking abstraction barriers? What will Windows 7 do anyway if I click debug?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? And I dont think Windows asked *you* to debug it. It needed some manual action from your side to perform the debug operation.

Comment: Don't ask what it will do... Try it!

Comment: Thanks, I can't reproduce the error, but the popup noted that "Virtualbox has stopped working. [Debug] [Close Application]".

Comment: Also, I did try clicking debug, and the Virtualbox window just hanged for five minutes. Afterwards, Visual Studio 2010 opened up and noted a null pointer error. How does this help me as the end user? Outlandish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your system is most likely set up for [postmortem debugging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/junfeng/from-unhandled-exception-to-debugger-attach).

I am not quite sure what makes Windows give the option to debug a failed process. Having a [debugger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) installed might certainly be part of the decision. Maybe a process can even force to have the debug option displayed after it fails.

Usually the option would be intended for developers only.

Possibly related reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396369/how-do-i-disable-the-debug-close-application-dialog-on-windows-vista

Comment: Thank you, the popup in that Stackoverflow question is exactly what went wrong. I do have a debugger installed since Visual Studio 2010 is installed.

Comment: @Oliver, yes, that is exactly how it works. When a crash occurs, Windows uses whatever debugger is indicated in the `AeDebug` registry key. By default, it is set to Dr. Watson which merely creates a crash dump and logs it, but if you have another debugger installed (which most programming environments will install for obvious reasons), it uses that instead. In that case, when a program crashes and Windows sees that you have a debugger installed, it asks you do handle the crash since it does not know if it is your own program that you are testing that crashed or a third-party program.

Answer (score 3):

If you have JIT debugging enabled in Visual Studio, or some other debugger, it will give you the opportunity to attach a debugger to a process that crashes so that you can do post-mortem debugging. If you don't want JIT debugging, you can disable it, and then you have to manually attach a debugger to a process you want to debug before it crashes.